# Drupal 7 user module customize for registration for different roles

Tags: php, drupal, module, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I have a requirement of customizing user signup form in Drupal 7. i am not getting any relevant help from the internet . so i thought i should ask the expert here.

Requirement is i have two roles say "Student" and "Teacher". I have to use default user module for their signup by setting their roles automatically.

Now there will be two links one for Student signup another for Teacher Sign up. When user click on Student SignUp i am hiding some fields of default user module which are suppose to fill by a teacher, so student will see only fields, which are specified. Same for Teacher i am hiding fields which student suppose to fill.

So basically with the use of default user module i have to perform the sign up process.

Solution what i think could be possible :

I can set a variable in the link saying "studetnSignUp?status=student" and same for Teacher "studetnSignUp?status=teacher". Now the problem is i can do this in php but do not have proficient way to the same in drupal.

If it can be possible with any other approach please let me know. As it is really urgent for me. Your support will be really appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can look into [Profile2](http://drupal.org/project/profile2) in combination with [Profile2 Registration Paths](http://drupal.org/project/profile2_regpath). It provides you with the ability to set a unique registration path for each Profile2 profile type. Per profile type you can define different fields. And I think a helpful feature is that it can assign user roles by registration path.

Comment: I tried this solution but after implementing i got this error

Fatal error: Cannot create references to/from string offsets nor overloaded objects in C:\wamp\www\abc\includes\common.inc on line 6518

Comment: I had not much to go on, but someone on drupal.stackexchange.com had a similar error: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/51401/fatal-error-when-changing-field-type-using-hook-form-alter If that doesn't help you, I suggest you describe in more detail what you already did, e.g. does "implementing" mean you just downloaded and enabled the aforementioned modules or did you e.g. already build custom forms with it?

Comment: i have figured out the fetal error. and registration with both roles is successful. but after registration how can i redirect them to a specific page , different for both.

Comment: You can use the Rules module for that. See also this answer: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/1791/9379

Answer (score 0):

I would grab the passed parameter using menu and then call

```
hook_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'user_profile_form') {
  // do your processing here
  }
}
```

alter the layout of the form dependant of the user, and specify the users role in the form to, ie teacher or student